# Why git pull from 2 branches deletes some modifications from the first branch?

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

I have this scenario:

1. branchA - with **some** modifications for 1.txt file
2. branchB - with **some other** modifications for 1.txt file
3. master - with old version of 1.txt file

I am in the master branch. First I pull `branchA` and get `branchA` modifications to 1.txt file.
then I pulled `branchB` and get its modifications to 1.txt file, **but that last pull also deleted the `branchA` modifications, and Git didn't show any conflict, why is that happening and how to prevent it**

Comment: What exact commands did you run to do these pulls? I believe the standard way to do what you are describing is to merge the branches into master, not pull.

Comment: @Gec I did it like this, I am on branch master: 1. git pull origin branchA. 2. git pull origin branchB. and correct me if I am wrong pull == fetch + merge?

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

We can't tell you without more information.  But you can find out why for yourself.

## Long

As you say in your comment, `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command* and the second command defaults to `git merge`.  So:

```
$ git checkout master
[various possible messages]
$ git pull origin branchA
[various possible messages]
$ git pull origin branchB
[more possible messages]
```

has your Git run `git fetch` twice, and `git merge` twice.  You can make this *more efficient* (on the computer, less efficient in terms of what you have to type in) by using `git merge` directly:

```
$ git checkout master
[various possible messages]
$ git fetch origin
[various possible messages]
$ git merge origin/branchA
[various possible messages]
$ git merge origin/branchB
[various possible messages]
```

and the outcome should be the same, given the same starting point, as long as the repository over at `origin` is not so super-active that the two different `git fetch` operations would do wildly different things.  This version is also easier to *describe*, so let's run with the longer but more efficient-for-Git variant.

> [After the first merge, I] get `branchA` modifications to 1.txt file.

Note that the files you see in your *working tree* are simply *extracted from* some commit(s).  The `git merge` command performs some action, and its action is a little complex; we'll come back to this in a moment.

> then I pulled `branchB` and get its modifications to 1.txt file, but that last pull also deleted the `branchA` modifications, and Git didn't show any conflict, why is that happening ...

To explain why, it's necessary to show just how `git merge` really works—and to get there, we must start with the basic building block of a Git repository, the *commit*.

Git is not really about *files*.  It's true that commits *contain* files, but a commit is a sort of all-or-nothing deal: you either have the commit, which means you have *all those files in exactly that form*, or you don't have the commit and you don't have its files at all.  It's also true that we (humans) *find* commits using the aid of *branch names*, and that Git organizes commits into things we call *branches*.<sup>1</sup>  But the [*raison d'être*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/raison%20d%27%C3%AAtre) for Git is really the commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>Humans call the branch *names* "branches", and call the commit-groups "branches", and sometimes call one particular commit "a branch", and may call remote-tracking names "branches".  For that matter, we call those brown things that stick out of tree trunks and eventually hold leaves "branches" too.<sup>2</sup>  So you need to watch out with the word "branch": think about whether you mean *one specific commit*, some *group of commits*, a *branch name*, or what, whenever you say or hear "branch".  The person who said or wrote it might mean something else!

<sup>2</sup>Arborists and tree science people—[dendrologists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrology)—have specific meanings for "trunk", "branch", "twig", and so on.  See the discussion [here](http://www.nativetreesociety.org/measure/longlimbs/trunks_vs_limbs_vs_branches.htm) and/or the information [here](https://extension.oregonstate.edu/node/113526/printable/print), for instance.

---

#### A commit is ...

Every Git commit has a *unique number*.  This number—expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) as a *hash ID*—is how Git actually finds and identifies the commit.  Git *needs* this hash ID to find the commit.  If Git didn't give us a better-for-humans alternative, we'd have to memorize all the hash IDs.  So of course, Git does give us an alternative.  But before we look at it, let's look at what's *in* a commit.

Each commit consists of two parts:

- The commit holds a *full snapshot of every file*, as a sort of permanent archive.  The files *in* this snapshot are stored in a special Git-only format where they're compressed and, importantly, have their contents *de-duplicated*.  So this means that if your new commit has 999 identical files and one different (edited) file, the new commit literally shares all 999 identical files with the previous commit.

  For this to work, *committed* files can never be changed.  As it happens, Git's magic numbering trick for commits already requires that *no part* of *any* commit ever be changed, so Git gets this for free.
- Meanwhile, separate from the snapshot, every commit holds some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  This includes things like the name and email address of the person who made the commit.  (The snapshot is actually handled indirectly, via a `tree` line in this metadata, which allows a new snapshot to completely reuse *everything* about a previous snapshot.  For instance, if you make a bad commit, then use `git revert` to undo the bad one by adding a correction, the new commit literally uses no space at all to hold the new snapshot, because it's 100% identical to the snapshot from two commits ago.  The new commit has new metadata, but re-uses an entire snapshot, rather than just parts of previous ones.)

The reason we care about the snapshot is obvious enough: those are the files that Git will "un-archive" for us when we ask Git to *extract* that snapshot.  The reason we care about the metadata is that it defines what `git log` shows us: who made the commit, when, and why, i.e., their log message.  But the metadata also include a *list of previous commit hash IDs*, and this is what forms commits into the chains that we call "branches".

**These commit chains are crucial to understanding how `git merge` works.**  Let's take a brief look at the mechanism.

*Most* Git commits store exactly one previous-commit hash ID in their metadata.  Git calls this one saved hash ID the *parent* of the commit, and we say that the commit *points to* its parent.  We can draw this, if we use letters to stand in for those big ugly hash IDs, by drawing the latest commit `H` with an arrow coming out of it, pointing backwards:

```
            <-H
```

Here `H` stands for "hash".  Because this "arrow" points to the previous commit, it's now time to draw in that previous commit.  Let's pick the previous letter `G` for that:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Since `G` *is* a commit, it has a snapshot and metadata, and its metadata holds one commit hash ID.  Commit `G` *points to* some still-earlier commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

This kind of backwards-pointing linkage lets Git work its way from the *last* commit in this chain, all the way back to the *very first commit ever*.  That commit, being the first one, has an empty list of previous commits, because there isn't any previous commit to get to.  So that's where `git log` has to stop.

#### Branch names find commits

I noted earlier that Git *needs* the actual hash ID, whatever that is, for commit `H` to *find* commit `H` in its object database.  We *could* just memorize it, and type it in, but who wants to memorize and retype `30cc8d0f147546d4dd77bf497f4dec51e7265bd8` for instance?  So Git gives us—humans—an alternative that is much easier for us.  Git's *references*—branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and all other kinds of names that Git lumps under this general term "reference"—let us type in a nice simple name like `master` or `branchA`.

The *name itself* simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  Whatever hash ID the name holds, that hash ID *is* the *last commit in the chain*.  So when we have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

the name `master` *means* "commit `H`", anywhere we use the name where Git needs a hash ID.

We can, at any time, create a *new branch name*.  We just need to make this name *point to* some existing commit.  For instance, if we create a new `br1` branch, pointing to `H`, we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, master
```

To remember which *branch name* we're using, Git attaches the special name `HEAD` to one of the branch names.  We'll skip most of this and move on to *remote-tracking names*.

#### `git fetch` and remote-tracking names

When you run `git fetch`, you are having your Git software, which works with your Git repository (your clone, on your laptop for instance) call up some *other* Git software, which is working with some *other* Git repository: a different clone.

That other Git software and repository, working together, have *their own branch names*.  These point to commits *they* have in *their* repository.

You may or may not have all the same commits.  Every commit is numbered, after all, with a *unique* number.  If you have a commit that has the *same number*, that means you have the *same commit*.  If you have commits that they don't, you'll have numbers that are just *missing* from their repository entirely.  The converse is true if they have commits *you* lack.

So, your `git fetch` has them list out *their* branch names and other references, and the hash IDs that go with these.  Since the *branch* names *define* the *latest* commits, any of their branch names that have a commit that you don't will show up here.

Fpr every commit they tell you about, that they have and you don't, your Git will ask their Git to *send* that commit to you.<sup>3</sup>  This also obliges their Git to offer the *parent(s)* of that commit, which your Git will check to see if you have.  If not, they must send the parents, and offer you the parents' parents, and so on.  In this way, you get from them *all* of their new commits that you don't already have.

Each `git fetch`, in other words, just adds to your [collective](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Borg_Collective).  You now have their commits in addition to any of your own that you've never given out.  (To *send* commits that you have, that they lack, you use `git push`.  This means push and fetch are as close as Git gets to opposites.  They're not exactly opposites, though.)

There's one problem: they have *branch names* for remembering their latest commits.  Your Git software can't just rip your branch names off *your* commits to make them remember *their* commits.  What if you've add a new `master`-branch commit that they don't have yet?  Then you have:

```
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
```

(see how your `master` now points to *your* latest commit, which is later than `H`?).  Meanwhile, *they* have some commit you are just now hearing of, commit `J`, that *their* `master` records:

```
...--G--H
         \
          J   <-- [their] master
```

(See how both `I` and `J` are *both later than* `H`?  Their `master` records the now-shared `J` commit.)

In your repository, you've now *added commit `J`* so you have:

```
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J   <-- [their] master
```

We'd like to to have our Git software set up some *name* in *our repository* to remember where *their* `master` pointed during this `git fetch`.  To achieve that, we have our Git turn their *branch* names into our *remote-tracking names:*

```
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          J   <-- origin/master
```

This `origin`-prefixed name, `origin/master`, is our Git's way of remembering their Git's branch names.

---

<sup>3</sup>This includes sending all of its files—but, due to the magic of Git's de-duplication and the way commits work, their Git and your Git can usually very quickly figure out which files you already have, and they can avoid sending you duplicates.  So, even though every commit has every file, and you get every new commit, you only get new-to-you *files*, just as you only get new-to-you *commits*.  Even then, they're magically compressed against files that their Git knows that you have.  This magic works poorly for certain cases of special clones, such as *shallow* clones, but we won't go into details here.

---

#### Your own setup (it's different and not something I can predict)

Let's suppose that your `master` is on commit `H`, and their `master` *was* on commit `H` before (which is why your own is also on `H` now):

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

You now run `git fetch origin`.  They've gone ahead and created some new commits and have some new branch names, so now you get:

```
          I   <-- origin/branchA
         /
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
      \  \
       \  J   <-- origin/master
        \
         K--L   <-- origin/branchB
```

Here, things get a little speculative.  **I can only *guess* what the graph looks like.**  You can *see* it: use `git log --graph`, or one of the many answers from [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452), to *see* what your graph looks like after `git fetch`, and before any `git merge`.

Note that to see this, you *must* use a separate `git fetch`, then some `git log` command or similar, *before* you run `git merge`.  If you run `git pull origin branchA`, and *then* look, it's too late!

#### Using `git merge`

**Merging is about combining work.**  In general, want Git to *combine work* we've done since some point, with work someone else has done since some point.  But sometimes there's nothing to *combine*.  In these cases, Git can *cheat*.

Let's go back to our `...-G-H` sequence:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Let's create two branch names, `br1` and `br2`, now:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, br2, master (HEAD)
```

Now let's `git switch br1` and make two new commits:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, master
```

Then we'll `git switch br2` and make two more new commits:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

We now switch back to `master`, or maybe `br1`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

... and run `git merge` and give it some other name (e.g., `br2`).  We're asking Git to combine work we did on one branch with work we did on another branch.  **What does this actually mean?**

The first problem with any such request is that commits don't store *changes*.  They only store *snapshots*.  Commit `J` has a full snapshot of all files, and commit `L` has a full snapshot of all files.  Commit `H` has a full snapshot of all files, too.

We can't just compare what's in `J` to what's in `L`.  Suppose we started out at commit `H` with a file with 100 lines.  Suppose that in commits `I-J` we added a few lines near the top, and in commits `K-L` we added a few lines near the bottom.  Comparing `J` vs `L` will tell us *delete the added lines in the top, and add instead the lines in the bottom*.

But hold on: our word-based description in the last paragraph above has the key clue: *Suppose we started out at commit `H` ...*  That is, in fact, *exactly what we did*.  But how should Git know this?

Well, take a look at the *graph*.  If we peel the distracting labels off it, we have:

```
          I--J
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L
```

It's almost blindingly obvious here: we were working along "in common", on the middle line, and then we "branched off" in two different directions, to make the top and bottom lines.  Git merely needs to find this *shared starting point*.  From there, it can determine what we changed, on each branch.

But suppose we're "on" `master`—that is, `HEAD` is attached to `master`, so that `H` is our *current commit*—and we run `git merge br1` to merge commit `I`.  (Note that merge works on *commits*, really; we're just using *names* like `br1` to find the commits.)  Git needs to find our *shared started point*.  [The algorithm Git uses for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs) takes the  commit graph as its input, and comes up with commit `H` ... which is the *commit we're using right now*.

The *general* merge algorithm says:

1. find the merge base;
2. run two `git diff` operations, from merge base to each tip commit;
3. *combine the changes* and apply to the snapshot from the merge base;
4. use the result as the snapshot to make a new *merge commit*.

One of our two `git diff` operations here will be:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-H>
```

The output from this `git diff` will be *empty*, because the snapshot in `H` exactly matches the snapshot in `H`.  There's no other possibility here!

(The other diff will compare `H` vs `J`, and thus see what work we did in `br1`, just like we want it to.)

The result of step 3—the "combining"—will be the set of changes from `H` to `J`, of course, because zero plus something is just the something.  So applying those same changes to `H` gets us the snapshot that's already there in `J`.  That means the *merge result snapshot* will *exactly match* the snapshot already in commit `J`.

If you *force* Git to make a real merge, Git will do that, and you'll get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /    \
...--G--H------M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

where `M` is our new *merge commit*.  (A merge commit is a commit with two or more parents; here, the two are `H` and then `J`, in that order, though this particular drawing doesn't show the order.)

But if you don't *force* it, Git will take a cheap short-cut and *not make any new commit at all*.  Git calls this a *fast-forward merge*, but there's no actual *merging* involved.  Git just does this:

```
          I--J   <-- br1, master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

That is, Git makes the *name* `master` point to commit `J`, just as the name `br1` points to `J`.

Having done this—i.e., not merged anything at all, just moved the branch name—we can now run `git merge br2`.  This time, Git *can't* cheat, because the *merge base*—the common starting point—is now commit `H`.  So this time Git has to run the two diffs:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

Git can then combine the two diffs—or at least, *try* to combine them; there may be a *merge conflict* here—and if all goes well, Git can make a new commit `M`, whose snapshot is the result of applying the *combined* diffs to the snapshot from the merge base commit `H`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- br2
```

#### Your experience

> but that [second merge] also deleted the branchA modifications, and Git didn't show any conflict ...

For this to happen, Git must have found the *merge base* somewhere, done the two `git diff`s, found that one side *didn't* change `1.txt`, and found that the other side *did* change `1.txt`, in such a way that the modification you expected to retain, got removed.

How, precisely, did that happen?  Well, that depends on which commit was the *merge base* commit in each of the two `git merge` operations you had Git run, and what diffs Git found when doing the merging.

To see what merge base(s) Git finds, use the `git merge-base` command.  It takes two commits (names or hash IDs) and spits out the hash ID(s) of the merge base(s):

```
git merge-base --all hash1 hash2
```

for instance.  The `--all` makes it list all the bases, if there are multiple merge bases; this particular case is somewhat rare, but if it happens, you have a *much more complicated* merge case, so it's worth checking.  See also the algorithm I linked above ([Lowest Common Ancestor in a DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs)).

Because you've *already done both merges*, this is a little tricky.  If both merges were *true merges*, `git log --graph` will show each of the two merge commits and, for each merge, both of its parents.  That will let you run `git merge-base --all` more easily.  But if at least one was a *fast-forward* merge, there's no trace of this merge left in the commit graph.  In this case, you'll need to use the *reflogs* (for HEAD and/or for the `master` branch) to observe the fast-forward operation and obtain the implied previous-branch-tip / merge base from there.

You can think of this as solving a murder mystery: who killed the line of code?  Was it Mr BranchA, in the library, with the rope?  Or was it Ms BranchB, in the conservatory, with the candlestick?  You must trace all the players' movements back from the time everyone was alive and well.  Sometimes it's obvious, when Mr BranchA has the collection of antique cannons and the murder victim was shot with a cannonball from an 1800s-era howitzer.  But you'll have to look at your particular situation: there's no single generic answer.

Comment: wow thanks a lot. I didn't finish reading it but I definitely will